# Saving and showing diary entries with cookies JS

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm extremely new to JS/HTML/CSS and for an assignment in college a few weeks ago we were asked to build a jS-fiddle which saves diary entries using cookies (You save by clicking a button) and one which will show diary entries using a different button. I was looking up about cookies on w3 schools here :http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp , but I don't think it was relevant for what I'm trying / I'm finding it hard to put it all together.

I know you'll need this for your html input box

```
Label: <input type="text" name=“somename” id="frm_somename"/>
```

And something like this for your JavaScript

```
var textValue = document.getElementById("frm_somename").value;
```

then your cookie code and at the end to return false (it's done on js fiddle so it shouldn't actually go anywhere).

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me connect the dots so I can save what it inputted in the box on a button click and return it with a different button click

Again I'm sorry if this seems stupid/useless/too easy for some people but I'm extremely new to web development

Comment: Just a head's up: This code will bite you: `input type="text" name=“somename” id="frm_somename"/>` as it is using SMART quotes, not regular ASCII quotes.

Comment: Have you looked up cookies? Tried to write any code to manipulate them?  There is a LOT of information out there....

Answer (score 0):

Well, cookies are always fun when it comes to manipulating them seeing how JavaScript doesn't have a built in functionality for handling the string that `document.cookie` returns; but with some of the `String` methods like `slice()` and `split()`, we can work around that. Here's a little fiddle to get you started, it's a simple way to add and check for a certain cookie, but it works.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0nctmxf7/2/)

[String.slice() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
[String.split() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
[Document.cookie docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
[encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
[decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)